# Is it against Google Webmaster Policy to accept paid guest blog posts?

Tags: seo, google, links

When people email me to "sponsor" or buy a blog post, is that illigal according to google rules?

Or is it only illegal when they request a straight up link placement in exchange for cash?

Also, will Google penalize me in terms of SEO if I have those sponsored blog posts?  Do they frown on such things?

Comment: how would google know if you paid or not for a blog post ?

Comment: @Vic someone could tell them, namely the person who paid if they didn't like something for example.  They can find out in a number of ways.

Comment: If you're at all concerned about this you could just nofollow any  links in the sponsored post that go to the sponsor's own site.

Comment: @Tim no one and nothing has cared about no-follow links since 2007 - very outdated/novice information you have there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to say it other way.. It's too risky for them to take into consideration such kind of reports.. Imagine the following situation: I have a blog. You don't know me. Now I'll write a review for your website, I'll post it to my blog, I'll photoshop a screenshot of my paypal transactions, I'll put your name there, and then I'll report to google. :) how does this sound to you ?... But, if google indexes thousands of links coming from blogs, I think this may raise some questions...

The only thing you should worry about are the TOS agreements and so on..

Comment: Google has a strong history of finding such things out.  The question is more of whether it is against their policy.

Answer (score 0):

YES!

> The following are examples of link schemes which can negatively impact
>   a site's ranking in search results:
>   ...
>
> - Buying or **selling links that pass PageRank**. This includes exchanging money for links, **or posts that contain links**...
>
>   ...
> - **Linking to web spammers or
>     unrelated sites with the intent to manipulate PageRank**

[ref. Official Google guide about Link schemes](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66356)

But according to the same phrase you are NOT creating a link schemes if you sell articles in your blogs as long as:

- your article does not contain a link at all
- OR your article does contain a link that does not pass PageRank, thus the link uses `rel="nofollow"` in `<a>` tag (or an in intermediate page of your site that is blocked by your robots.txt)

Obviously you can ignore what they suggest and think: *"well how does Google will ever know I'm selling blog articles?!"*

**IMHO** (i don't work for Google) if you sell an article with links that pass PageRank just once in a while it'll be hard for Google to spot your blog as an affiliate of link schemes, but if you often sell articles with links, and **even worst the links in the articles are not (or poorly) related to the main subjects of your blog**, I would be careful.
Moreover new tools like the [disavow links](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.it/2012/10/a-new-tool-to-disavow-links.html) provided to Webmasters along with the [spam report for paid links](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport) could easily change any webmaster into a squeaker.